# Ребят незнаю как цикл пристроить помогите

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, циклы, переменные

Senior Front end разработчик Иван уже не первый год думает о том, чтобы положить деньги на депозит в банк на несколько лет. Он ознакомился с условиями банка Mate bank и узнал, что если он положит 10000 долларов на 3 года под 4 процента годовых, он получит через 3 года 1248,64 долларов прибыли.

Первый год 10000 + 4% = 10400
Второй год 10400 + 4% = 10816 и так далее ...
Сейчас банкиры Mate bank считают все это вручную. Давай создадим функцию calculateProfit, которая будет принимать параметры amount, period, percent, и возвращать сумму чистой прибыли за этот период.

примеры:

calculateProfit (1000, 5, 7) === 407
calculateProfit (12500, 3, 12) === 5322

```
    function getYears(amount, percent, period) {
        const sum = amount;
        for (let i = 0; i< 2;i++) {
         sum +=  (amount*(percent/100));
         }
      }
           return sum;
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1):

```
for (let i = 0; i < period; i++) {
  sum = sum * (1 + percent / 100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getYears(amount, percent, period){
    let start_amount = amount;
    for (let i = 0; i < period; i++){
       amount +=  (amount / 100) * percent;
       }
   return amount - start_amount;
   }
```

Comment: Не работаеть...

Comment: Ну ето неверный ответ